# How to return a color from input type = color

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I have been trying this for a while so i'll do my best to explain

You can use `<input type="color"/>` to get a simple color picker...
My question is after I pick a color and click "ok" or am done choosing how do return the color I picked?

If anyone knows how to do this please share! Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `value` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as it is an `input` type, you can just get the value of the element.

Answer (score 2):

Access the `value` property of the node, following the `change` event:

```
var input = document.getElementById('colorInputElement');

function newColor () {
    console.log(this.value);
}

input.addEventListener('change', newColor);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bpdSG/).

Tested, and verified, only in Chromium 27/Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to get this back? Serverside (php,...) or clientside (js)?

Serverside: get the post variable, dump it and check the format.

Clientside: get the value with
    jQuery(element).val();

Comment: Why would jQuery be necessary to access the `value` of an `input`?

Comment: JQuery was just one of the many possibilities. Why not add it to the list?

Comment: I've no criticism of *adding* it to the list, I asked because it seemed that you had a list of *one* (for client-side solutions), of which you didn't explain the reason for choosing over either plain JavaScript, or any other library. Nor did you mention that it was, in fact, a library, and that it would have to be explicitly included in the document in order to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other input, you can get the value by `document.getElementById('ID').value`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rc6x/)